# Debian 10 (buster) - gdm3 only starts after "systemctl restart gdm3"

Tags: debian, gnome3, gdm, gdm3

I've currently set up a new install of Debian stretch. I followed [the description on how to update to Debian Testing (buster)](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) and everything went perfectly. I rebooted the system, and everything went fine.

Next I compiled a 4.19.5 Kernel on this System for my System:

```
$ git clone -b kernel_4.19.y git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git
$ cd linux
$ cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
$ yes "" | make oldconfig
$ make -j64 bzImage modules
$ sudo make modules_install install
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo reboot
```

Compiling the kernel went flawless, the kernel boots, everything works fine. Except `gdm3`: It wont start after booting the Kernel.

So I again booted the Debian 4.18.y kernel but still just have a black screen. Booting 4.19.5 again, I ssh'd from a different machine on this machine and issued `systemctl restart gdm3`. After 2-4 seconds, the login-screen pops up on my display and everything works as intended.

Again, rebootet the system. No login-screen, just black. Again, ssh'd on the machine, restarted `gdm3`, everything pops up as it should be.

I've digged around in the logs of `gdm3` when it wont start.

```
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) config/udev: removing GPU device /sys/devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:03.1/0000:43:00.0/drm/card0 /dev/dri/card0
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: xf86: remove device 0 /sys/devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:03.1/0000:43:00.0/drm/card0
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: failed to find screen to remove
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: dbus-daemon[1264]: [session uid=103 pid=1264] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.0' (uid=103 pid=1176 comm="/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session gnome-session --autost")
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: dbus-daemon[1264]: [session uid=103 pid=1264] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmManager: trying to register new display
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: Unable to register display with display manager
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (**) Option "fd" "25"
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (**) Option "fd" "28"
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (**) Option "fd" "29"
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) event16 - Cherry USB keyboard: device removed
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (**) Option "fd" "30"
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) event18 - Cherry USB keyboard System Control: device removed
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (**) Option "fd" "31"
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) event19 - Cherry USB keyboard Consumer Control: device removed
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (**) Option "fd" "32"
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) event20 - PixArt Cherry USB Optical Mouse: device removed
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:84
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:83
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Nov 28 12:11:46 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:82
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:80
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:64
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) RADEON(0): RADEONCloseScreen
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1176]: (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmSession: Emitting 'session-exited' signal with exit code '70'
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmSession: stopping conversation gdm-launch-environment
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmSessionWorkerJob: Stopping job pid:1170
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmCommon: sending signal 15 to process 1170
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmDisplay: Greeter exited: 70
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: display status changed: 4
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmDisplay: finish display
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmDisplayStore: Unreffing display: 0x55da450b4350
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmDisplay: Disposing display
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmCommon: sending signal 15 to process -1176
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: Child process -1176 was already dead.
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmSession: Closing session
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmSession: Stopping all conversations
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmSessionWorkerJob: Stopping job pid:1170
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmCommon: sending signal 15 to process 1170
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmSessionWorkerJob: Waiting on process 1170
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmCommon: process (pid:1170) done (status:0)
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmSessionWorkerJob: SessionWorkerJob died
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmSession: Disposing session
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmSession: Closing session
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmSession: Stopping all conversations
Nov 28 12:11:47 bamdevsrv gdm3[1102]: GdmDisplay: Finalizing display: /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Displays/94395949597520
```

Finally it is stuck at `Finalizing display`.
After I issue an restart, the logs look nearly identical, but it continues after `Finalizing display` with a lot of other output.

```
Nov 28 13:59:16 bamdevsrv gdm3[1129]: GdmSession: Disposing session
Nov 28 13:59:16 bamdevsrv gdm3[1129]: GdmSession: Closing session
Nov 28 13:59:16 bamdevsrv gdm3[1129]: GdmSession: Stopping all conversations
Nov 28 13:59:16 bamdevsrv gdm3[1129]: GdmDisplay: Finalizing display: /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Displays/93976516326224
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[1129]: GDM finished, cleaning up...
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[1129]: GdmDisplayStore: Clearing display store
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: Enabling debugging
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: Changing user:group to Debian-gdm:Debian-gdm
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: Successfully connected to D-Bus
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmManager: GDM starting to manage displays
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GLib: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: Could not ping plymouth: Failed to execute child process “/bin/plymouth” (No such file or directory)
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: enumerating seats from logind
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: wayland login display for seat seat0 requested
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: Adding display on seat seat0
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmDisplay: id: (null)
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmDisplay: seat id: (null)
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmDisplay: session class: greeter
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmDisplay: initial: no
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmDisplay: allow timed login: yes
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmDisplay: local: yes
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmDisplay: session type: wayland
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmDisplay: seat id: seat0
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmDisplay: initial: yes
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmDisplayStore: Adding display /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Displays/94188358636112 to store
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmDisplay: Managing display: /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Displays/94188358636112
Nov 28 14:02:49 bamdevsrv gdm3[2448]: GdmDisplay: Preparing display: /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Displays/94188358636112
```

How is gdm3 broken on boot, but not after I restart it?

**Edit:**
Currently I'm running a workaround. But this is nothing other than an ugly hack as new systemd service:

```
[Unit]
After=gdm3.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 15
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart gdm3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2):

[wiki.debian.org](https://wiki.debian.org) DebianTesting
has specific instructions for gdm

```
apt-get --reinstall install gdm3
apt-get --reinstall install gnome
apt-get --reinstall install gnome-shell

dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Comment: Tried this several times. Same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced a similiar issue without gnome starting at boot.

dmesg (for me) showed a segfault in gnome-shell due to weyland.

Updating the daemon.conf in /etc/gdm3/ with "WaylandEnable=false" removed the segfault error and lead to gnome starting (on boot) without further issue.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059091/gnome-shell-error-showing-in-dmesg